# Neural Network - distinguishing between several normalized values is impossible?

Tags: rnn

It's a common practice to normalize inputs to the neural Network.

Let's assume we have a vector of activations.

One of techniques, the [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf) simply looks at the vector's components,  re-centers this activated vector from $\mu$ to zero, then divides by the standard deviation $\sigma$

How is it then possible to distinguish activations [1,2,3,4] from [4,5,6,7]  if both will be re-centered to the same vector [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.5f]  and then divided by std deviation? Also, I can see such a problem when merely normalizing the input-state-vectors for any Neural Net.

**Edit:**

there seems to be a hint in [first half of page 4 in the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf), however due to my weakness in Maths I can't comprehend it :(

**Edit after accepted the answer:**

guys, don't forget that Layer Norm (and Batch norm) both have **Gain** and **Bias** terms. If the network performs poorly, the **gain** is tweaked to undo division-by-std-deviation, and tweaking the **bias** is used to undo the shift (the re-centering). This allows some neurons to indeed pay attention to scaling and shifting, when really required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math you are talking about is in equation (7):

> Let x′ be a new data point obtained by re-scaling x by δ. Then we have,
>   [image]
>
> It is easy to see re-scaling individual data points does not change
>   the model’s prediction under layer normalization. Similar to the
>   re-centering of the weight matrix in layer normalization, we can also
>   show that batch normalization is invariant to re-centering of the
>   dataset.

It proves that the prediction over x' would be the same as in x. So what you say is right, they are indistinguishable.

And I think this is what we want because improves generalization in predictions!

For example in image classification, you are trying to detect orangutangs, if an image  ***I*** represent an orangutang, ( ***I*** x 5)+2 still is an orangutang!

Comment: Thanks! So is it then only for classification tasks?

Comment: No I guess is the same even in regression!